# How can I get the quote for the terms in other aggs in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

## Hi everyone

I am using ELK to analyse log.

And I want to get the quote for terms aggregator in another aggregator，because I want to use the doc_count in the terms result.

Is there any recommonds?

## Thank you for your help.

Comment: Could you explain better? If I understand well you would have an aggregation on a field - eg IpAddress - and on all this entries - the ips - you would make another aggregation - eg the status_code- is right?

Comment: Thank you  for your help.What I want to explain is: I use an aggregation to count the user and his corresponding count of viewed the website.Then I want to count how many does it have that the people viewed the websites for 5 times or other number.